# ObservableValidator CustomValidation validates too early

Tags: .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a .Net MAUI app that uses CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. The viewmodel is validated using ObservableValidator with custom validation:

```
 public partial class BasePageModel : ObservableValidator
 ...

public partial class DistributorsLocatorPageModel : BasePageModel
{
     ...
    [ObservableProperty]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(DistributorsLocatorPageModel), nameof(ValidateProductLines))]
    private List<ProductLineListItem> _productLines;

    ...
    public static ValidationResult ValidateProductLines(List<ProductLineListItem> productLines, ValidationContext context)
    {
        bool isValid = productLines.Where(pl => pl.Selected).Any();

        if (isValid)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new("Please Choose Product Line!");
    }
```

Here is XAML:

```
                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductLines}" >
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:ProductLineListItem">
                                    <Grid
                                        ColumnDefinitions="*,auto"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" Style="{StaticResource SwitchStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
```

For some reason, this validation fires without any call to ValidateAllProperties(), as soon as the view is loaded, thus always showing the error message "Please Choose Product Line!" before the user has chance to choose anything. What am I missing?

P.S. Regular (non-custom) validation behaves as expected.

Comment: The symptom suggests that it triggers when something on the page binds to ProductLines, because it transitions from "no items" (when not bound) to "has items" (when bound). I think *don't* attach validation to that list. What "changes" (when user selects) isn't the list; its the selection of an item in some ListView (or similar). Show the xaml that binds to that list. Show whatever code sets "Selected" property on an item. You'll need the event or command of selection change to call that validation method. Sorry, hazy on details.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for the input. I added xaml code to my question. Selection is not changed programmatically, only by the user's click.

Comment: *"Selection is not changed programmatically, only by the user's click."* That's fine. The xaml `<Switch IsToggled={"Binding Selected"}` is what I was looking for. When that changes (by user toggling switch), you "somehow" need to trigger that validation. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that, because that is connected to one item, but the validator is on the page (because it needs to look at the whole list of items). Maybe someone else can figure this out.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve No, I don't need to validate on change. The whole form is validated when submitted. The problem is that this custom validator fires when the view is just loaded, and of course that validation fails, as nothing is selected  yet.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it just stopped doing that. I made various changes since I asked the question, so I have no idea what fixed that...